# erriding the selected background color for a themed tabitem

Tags: wpf, styles, controltemplate, overriding, tabitem

I'm trying to do something which I'd think would be pretty simple, but is turning out to be rather complicated.
I'm working with a TabControl that has already been styled by a theme in an included assembly, but I'd like the background color of a TabItem when the TabItem is selected to be different. While I could change this on the theme in the other assembly, I'd rather just override it for my application.

The problem seems to be that setting the background color for selected TabItems involves setting a control template, and in particular, a control template trigger on the IsSelected property. I can't find an easy way to only override that one trigger without fully defining the control template like so (resulting in a bunch of unnecessary copy/pasted code). Here's what I have right now- is there a way to cut this down to target only the part I care about? It doesn't seem like ControlTemplates are inheritable. Thanks for any help you can offer.

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Name="Border"
                        Margin="0,0,-4,0"
                        Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static themes:HarmonyBrushes.BrushDKey}}"
                        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static themes:HarmonyBrushes.BrushDKey}}"
                        BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
                        CornerRadius="3,3,0,0">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            ContentSource="Header"
                            Margin="12,2,12,2"
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border"
                            Property="Background"
                            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static themes:HarmonyBrushes.BrushLightKey}}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border"
                            Property="BorderBrush"
                            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static themes:HarmonyBrushes.BrushLightKey}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static themes:HarmonyBrushes.TextBrushLightKey}}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border"
                            Property="BorderThickness"
                            Value="1,1,1,0" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border"
                            Property="Background"
                            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static themes:HarmonyBrushes.BrushDarkKey}}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border"
                            Property="BorderBrush"
                            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static themes:HarmonyBrushes.BrushDarkKey}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static themes:HarmonyBrushes.BrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static themes:HarmonyBrushes.TextBrushLightKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to change the colour is to override the resource:

```
      <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
          <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static themes:HarmonyBrushes.BrushLightKey}" Color="Green" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <TabControl>
          <TabItem>Tab One</TabItem>
          <TabItem>Tab Two</TabItem> 
        </TabControl>
      </Grid>
```

Comment: I thought about doing that- the problem is that the theme I'm using reuses their brushes all over the place, so even if I only change that locally to each tabitem, it will most likely change more than just the color of the selected tab.